# Part name in Pspice

Tags: components, pspice, non-linear

I was working on some simulations in logistic map in MATLAB, and need to verify some results in a virtual circuit of a logistic map. I found this circuit diagram for the logistic map.

[image]

However, I am having some trouble finding two parts of this circuit in PSPICE.

First, what should I search for to get the box with '{R}', which is basically multiplying by a scalar value 'R'?

Second, what is that part below 'TD = {delay}'? I haven't yet been introduced to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything with curly braces is a [parameter](http://www.pspice.com/how-define-model-parameter-so-it-visible-schematic-and-easily-editable-schematic) or in some spice packages a conversion to a scalar value. In this case the parameter {R} is set to 3 (probably with a .param statement in the netlist or graphically in the paramters list). It means the voltage is being multiplied by a power of 3.

The second thing is a [transmission line](http://www.pspice.com/resources/application-notes/transmission-line-modeling) with an impedance of Z_0 = 1k and a delay of 100us

Comment: Also, how do I get that circle with a plus as well as a minus in it?

Comment: I'll give you one more, but you should really start to learn how to use their documentation http://www.pspice.com/resources/application-notes/analog-behavioral-modeling